Configure Cloud CDN for Static file with Cloud function
I have a bucket in Google Cloud Storage, which I want to configure in two ways –

Make it a CDN hosted file – I want to be able to download the file directly. I am able to do this, but not run a cloud function

Run a cloud function every time this file is downloaded – when I set this up, I loose access to the static URL that gets replaced by the cloud function URL. Now this runs the cloud function every time, but obviously, since the URL is not static, I am loosing on caching benefits by the browser.


I want to achieve both in Google cloud. Looks like only one of them is possible at a time.
Goal – run a cloud function once every new GET request is made to the file.
Do I have to use a different CDN function that treats Google Cloud as an origin? Can both be achieved in Google Cloud itself?

You can't configure a Cloud Storage bucket to run a function on every download.  The Cloud Storage triggers types are listed in the documentation (finalized/uploaded, deleted, archived, metadata updated). Downloading is not a supported event.
Your only real option to get a trigger here, using the products you mentioned, is to write an HTTP trigger that accepts the path to an object to download, downloads it directly from the bucket, and sends the object data to the caller.  By doing so, however, you are bypassing any and all benefits of a CDN, which does not have any hooks into Cloud Functions.
It's just not possible to get everything you're asking for in your question.

Oh. Thanks for the insight. I could get a cloud function URL that ran every time when called and it gave me a modified version (I was adding timestamp in the file). Just that the URL was not ending in .js but rather the name of the function: cloud.com/function/modifyfile/ - Is there a way to have this function run when a CDN object is requested by a client, that is, similar to AWS’s onClientRequest ➞ onOriginRequest ➞ onOriginResponse (run function) ➞ onClientResponse (deliver static file to client).

”downloads it directly from the bucket, and sends the object data to the caller” – this is fine for me as long as the URL is a static one which Browser could cache. I will have some CDN benefit that way. Is it not possible?

If you have a new question, please post it separately.
